# Как правильно передать RSAParameters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Сабж.
Пробую
`string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<RSAParameters>(_publicKey);` в ответ получаю `"{}"`
По этому делаю так

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));  
xs.Serialize(sw, _publicKey);
string stringKey = sw.ToString();
```

Далее так

```
Keys key = new Keys(stringKey);
```

В этом классе просто string поле в которое я пишу XML.

```
 string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<Keys>(key);
```

И эту строку передаю POST запросом в контроллер другого приложения.

> Зачем XML пихать в класс а потом класс в json? Ну у меня просто не получилось в контролере принять строку XML.

В контролере я принимаю объект, десереализую, и записываю строку с XML в файл, получается что то подобное

```XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RSAParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <Modulus>rpB3UeQPCwikIsZxy19KKkhH0/PtgOV11aMNi5hB6zYiIM4p1rN0tJDYFqTbd98ajk4pff+/IiZ9Iy/gsuW1JUVgaZcw6b1M85cKdz3Ws3Ewc5j6Ub80mmK1xbGq599zJPQmj2fJ7p8bqM8i6WeVQxD87/vrycwVDtXCD/4SI5UOk1DFja4NVSPKmTxjU4XejAGw8HlhhE5UB48SfppdJHdiFuMhO8LDxgRFEim6fIyymzl9IuVc+CRObRzIyeSXQd0+8ldeFkKao+MTJcVq1cHWCpfZF4zVO6L37xG5Sz18a4s7NBfIv9owt6XpcRgl/bv1FgpFPwhWYFlN+iq/eQ==</Modulus>
</RSAParameters>
```

Далее я пытаюсь десереализовать этот файл но получаю ошибку

```cs
public RSAParameters _publicKey;
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("note.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    publicKey = (RSAParameters)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Ошибка

```
There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
```

Смысл этого всего в том что я хочу отправить публичный ключ, а в ответ получить зашифрованное сообщение этим ключом, а потом расшифровать его.

Comment: Когда у вас не получилось бинарные данные запихать в json - надо было их предварительно обернуть в base64 -- и не пришлось бы городить огород с конвертацией в xml.

Comment: Вы забыли принять ответ в прошлом вашем вопросе.

Comment: Я не забыл, я не могу решить какой ответ лучший, вот думаю подождать до вечера, и посмотреть какой больше + наберет тот и помечу как ответ.

Comment: Я тоже не до конца понимаю, зачем это всё с XML здесь. `Convert.ToBase64String()`